# Remove stretch between index entries

Tags: spacing, memoir, indexing, imakeidx

These are the gaps I'm talking about. This seems similar to what happens when using `\flushbottom`.

For context, I am using `imakeidx` with `memoir`.

I've tried turning on `\raggedbottom` and setting `\parskip` to `0pt`, both with little success.

[image]

Comment: Those don't look like "stretches" to me, but blank lines intentionally put there to separate one letter of the alphabet and the next (Notice, e.g., they occur between the last 'm'-entry and first 'n' entry, the last 'p'-entry and first 'q'-entry.) If you wanted to remove them, a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your code would speed things along.

Comment: With a fairly minimal set up, I think `\renewcommand{\indexspace}{}` might work (rerun makeindex), but it's hard to tell for sure for your document without seeing any code.

Comment: @frabjous has the answer.  These spaces are introduced intentionally to make it easier for a reader to find an entry more quickly.  Sometimes, the "key letter" is actually set in that location to make the transition even more obvious.

Comment: ahhhh that makes much more sense! Now that I know why it's there it doesn't bother me anymore, thank you!